# Using multiple result sets java jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

I used four different result sets and four separate statements to create a table. One of the result set is working fine while another gives null values.
resultset1 only gives the first value in the set. Is there any way to fix this?

Here's the code :

```
package userInterface;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import reu.FileMod;
import reu.ImageSend;
import reu.ColumnAutoSizer;

public class TabOne extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
private JButton button1, button2;
public static JTable table;
private ImageSend img;
private JPanel orderPanel;
private Connection connection;
private ResultSet result1, result2, result3, result4;
private String[] teacher, hall, batch, days;

public TabOne() {

    img = new ImageSend();
    orderPanel = new JPanel();
    button1 = new JButton("Save");
    button2 = new JButton("Refresh");
    button2.setIcon(img.createImage("/image/update.png"));
    button2.setBorderPainted(false);
    button2.setFocusPainted(false);
    button2.setContentAreaFilled(false);

    button1.setIcon(img.createImage("/image/small_save.png"));
    button1.setBorderPainted(false);
    button1.setFocusPainted(false);
    button1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button1.addActionListener(this);
    table = new JTable();
    createTabOne();

}

private void createTabOne() {

    setOrderPanel();

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    // panel border

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

    Dimension dim = getPreferredSize();
    dim.height = 100;

    // panel color

    setBackground(new Color(46, 139, 87));

    table.setRowHeight(22);
    table.setFont(new Font("times new roman", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    table.getTableHeader().setFont(
            new Font("times new roman", Font.BOLD, 16));
    /*
     * table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
     * public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
     * ColumnAutoSizer.sizeColumnsToFit(table); } });
     */
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Table Mod

    orderPanel.setPreferredSize(dim);
    add(orderPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

}

private void setOrderPanel() {

    Border inner = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Order Section");
    Border outer = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5);

    orderPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outer, inner));

    orderPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    orderPanel.setBackground(new Color(147, 197, 114));

    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gc.weightx = 0;
    gc.weighty = 0;
    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

    button1.setFont(new Font("times new roman", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    orderPanel.add(button1, gc);

    // gc.weightx = 0.5;
    // gc.weighty = 0.5;
    gc.gridx = 2;
    gc.gridy = 1;
    button2.setFont(new Font("times new roman", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    orderPanel.add(button2, gc);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    /*
     * JButton ob = (JButton) e.getSource(); FileMod.saveFile();
     */

    exeQuery();
}

private void disconnect() throws Exception {
    if (connection != null)
        connection.close();

}

private void connect() throws Exception {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school";

    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");

}

public void exeQuery() {

    try {

        connect();

        String day, hall, batch, name;

        DefaultTableModel tableModel;
        String[] head = { "Day", "Hall Name", "Batch", "Lecturer Name" };
        tableModel = new DefaultTableModel() {
            public boolean isCellEditable(int arg0, int arg1) {
                return false;
            };
        };
        tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(head);
        table.setModel(tableModel);

        day = null;
        name = null;
        hall = null;
        batch = null;

        getTeacher();
        getHall();
        getBatch();
        getDays();

        while (result4.next()) {

            day = result4.getString(2);

            while (result2.next()) {

                hall = result2.getString(2);

                if (result3.next()) {
                    batch = result3.getString(2);
                } else {
                    batch = "null";
                }

                if (result1.next()) {
                    name = result1.getString(3);
                    name = name + " " + result1.getString(2);
                } else {
                    name = "null";
                }
            }

            tableModel.addRow(new String[] { day, hall, batch, name });
        }

        disconnect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void getTeacher() throws Exception {

    PreparedStatement search1 = connection
            .prepareStatement("select * from lecturer");
    result1 = search1.executeQuery();

}

public void getHall() throws Exception {

    PreparedStatement search2 = connection
            .prepareStatement("select * from hall");
    result2 = search2.executeQuery();

}

public void getBatch() throws Exception {

    PreparedStatement search3 = connection
            .prepareStatement("select * from batch");
    result3 = search3.executeQuery();

}

public void getDays() throws Exception {

    PreparedStatement search4 = connection
            .prepareStatement("select * from day_of_week");
    result4 = search4.executeQuery();

}

}
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: this is really ugly. rewrite to make all the resultsets local variables, read from them and close them before you return from the method.

Comment: Apart from the suggestion by Nathan, you might want to disable autocommit, as it can (will) close result sets when another statement is executed.

Comment: Do not nest the for loops. If you have only one batch row, then your code will have null after the first day.